# How to set a break on objc_weak_error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsnetservicebrowser

In my app I sometimes get this error:

```
objc[3899]: __weak variable at 0x610000056bd0 holds 0x10003 instead of 0x610000302640. This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.
```

How do I set a break on "objc_weak_error". Should I set it like this?
[image]
Probably not, I tried with and without quotation marks. As I get no break when the error occurs something is not right.

Comment: Try to add **Symbolic Breakpoint**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add Symbolic Breakpoint:
[image]

Comment: fro some reason this break point does not stop on the error. Guessing it is safe to take that my crash my not be related to "This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak()"